# how do i get a sound on click and also show the 7 in the calculator display

Tags: javascript, html

```js
document.getElementById("a").onclick = function(){
 var a_toets = document.getElementById("audio_a");
 a_toets.play();
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
  case 55:  var a_toets = document.getElementById("audio_a");
            a_toets.play();
  break;
 }
})

var inputLabel = document.getElementById('inputLabel');

function pushBtn(obj) {

    var pushed = obj.innerHTML;

    if (pushed == '=') {
        //berekenen
        inputLabel.innerHTML = eval(inputLabel.innerHTML);
    
    } else if (pushed == 'AC') {
        //alles weg
        inputLabel.innerHTML = '0';

    } else {
        if (inputLabel.innerHTML == '0') {
            inputLabel.innerHTML = pushed;

        } else {
            inputLabel.innerHTML += pushed;

        }
    }
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
* {
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
    color: #555;
}
body {
    background-color: #3fb399;
}
.container {
    width: 320px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 120px auto;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-color: #f4f4f4;
}
td {
    width: 25%;
}
button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
}
#inputLabel {
    height: 120px;
    font-size: 40px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 16px;
    background-color: #ececec;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>rekenmachine</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" id="inputLabel">0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">AC</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">/</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button id="a" onclick="pushBtn(this);">7</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">8</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">9</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">*</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">4</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">5</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">6</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">-</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">1</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">2</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">3</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">+</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">0</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">.</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">=</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <audio id="audio_a">
                <source src="https://www.zapsplat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/sound-effects-18146/zapsplat_multimedia_click_001_19367.mp3?_=1" type="audio/mpeg">
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
              </audio>

        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

i have to make a calculator with html css js.
i have the calculator and it works very good. but now i have added a sound (mp3 link) to one key. the sound is working when you click on the key. but the key is not longer working as an calculator. so the key isn't showing on the calculator display. so you cant langer calculate with that key. how can i fix that?

i hope you can help me with this. i want a sound on the key and i want that it works as before as a normal calculator.  [this is my html and js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75bcL.png)

Comment: Could you please add your code in snippet?

Comment: sure. i have done it

Comment: Have you tried to play the audio inside your `pushBtn` function?

Comment: no how can i do that im just a beginner

Comment: As you see you used onclick in html and onclick in js both. So one works. Choose one and put all codes you want to do in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play the audio inside your `pushBtn` function :

```js
var a_toets = document.getElementById("audio_a");
var inputLabel = document.getElementById('inputLabel');

function pushBtn(obj) {
   a_toets.play();
    var pushed = obj.innerHTML;

    if (pushed == '=') {
        //berekenen
        inputLabel.innerHTML = eval(inputLabel.innerHTML);
    
    } else if (pushed == 'AC') {
        //alles weg
        inputLabel.innerHTML = '0';

    } else {
        if (inputLabel.innerHTML == '0') {
            inputLabel.innerHTML = pushed;

        } else {
            inputLabel.innerHTML += pushed;

        }
    }
}
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
* {
    font-family: 'Inconsolata', monospace;
    color: #555;
}
body {
    background-color: #3fb399;
}
.container {
    width: 320px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 120px auto;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-color: #f4f4f4;
}
td {
    width: 25%;
}
button {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    font-size: 24px;
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
    transition-duration:0.3s;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #a4dfff;
}

button:active {
    background-color: #30ff62;
}

#inputLabel {
    height: 120px;
    font-size: 40px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 16px;
    background-color: #ececec;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>rekenmachine</title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Inconsolata" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" id="inputLabel">0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">AC</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">/</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">7</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">8</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">9</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">*</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">4</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">5</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">6</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">-</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">1</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">2</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">3</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">+</button></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">0</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">.</button></td>
                    <td><button onclick="pushBtn(this);">=</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <audio id="audio_a">
                <source src="https://www.zapsplat.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/sound-effects-18146/zapsplat_multimedia_click_001_19367.mp3?_=1" type="audio/mpeg">
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
              </audio>

        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes it works thank you!! one more question. how can i add this sound to every key?

Comment: It's already added to all keys because the function `pushBtn` fires with all keys.

Comment: okay thanks, how can i get a onmouseover and onclick? i want that the color changes than

Comment: You can use `CSS :hover` to change color when mouse over. like : `button:hover { background-color: red; }` and to make a smooth transaction add `transition-duration : 0.3s` inside the main style `button {  }`. **i have updated the code above**

Comment: Also, you can use `button:active` to change color when user click on the button.